# Google form script not working

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I can't seem to get a form-triggered script to run right. To be precise, it runs, and I can do some things, but I can't access the form data that is supposed to be sent to the event handler function.

I've got a very simple script triggered by a Google Sheet form:

```
function OnFormSubmit(e)
{
  try {
    var timeStamp = e.namedValues["Timestamp"][0];
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "SCRIPT ENTRY", timeStamp); 
  } catch (x) {
    var message = x.toString() + "\n[" + Utilities.jsonStringify(e) + "]\n"
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "SCRIPT ERROR", message); 
    }
}
```

I've also got a very simple form with just one item. I've got the trigger set up. The form runs and adds a line to the spreadsheet. I get email, so the script is triggering. However I get the SCRIPT ERROR email. The message is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "Timestamp" from undefined.
[{"response":"FormResponse","authMode":"FULL"}]
```

The "Timestamp" does indeed exist in the Form Response sheet (as I believe it always will; Timestamp is an automatic entry).

It seems that OnFormSubmit() is not being passed the parameter I think it's supposed to get passed. But all the examples I see work like this.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using a script in a form (as can be seen from the value in object e) and not from within a spreadsheet.

You should be using the forResponse class [documented here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response), you'll see that methods are completely different, I'm not going to reproduce the doc here but for example the time stamp comes using [getTimestamp()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getTimestamp%28%29).